# Running PS1 from windows 10 command prompt

Tags: powershell, batch-file, command-line, windows-10

I'm trying to run a PowerShell from command prompt but received an error.

PS in command prompt:

```
powershell -command "Get-Date (Invoke-Command { (New-Object -com """Microsoft.Update.AutoUpdate""").Results.LastInstallationSuccessDate} -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).date -format yyyyMMdd | Out-File -FilePath C:\temp\winupdatelatest.txt"
```

Error:

```
Get-Date : Cannot bind parameter 'Date' to the target. Exception setting "Date": "Cannot convert null to type
"System.DateTime"."
At line:1 char:10
+ Get-Date (Invoke-Command { (New-Object -com "Microsoft.Update.AutoUpd ...
+          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (:) [Get-Date], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterBindingFailed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetDateCommand
```

Please help.

Comment: That's a giant inline PS script. It has constituent pieces. To troubleshoot you need to take the pieces apart and run them indivdually to see what's going on.

Comment: Basically, this command `(New-Object -com """Microsoft.Update.AutoUpdate""").Results.LastInstallationSuccessDate` failed and you didn't see the actual error because of `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue`

Comment: It might have something to do with quoting - is there any reason you need to use powershell.exe here rather than just running this in a `.ps1`

Comment: Does this work for you? `Get-Date (Invoke-Command { (New-Object -com "Microsoft.Update.AutoUpdate").Results.LastInstallationSuccessDate} -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).date -format yyyyMMdd`